# How to uninstall or remove policy-demo in Calico

Tags: calico

new to **calico**, trying to secure Kubernetes cluster using **calico**.
I have installed `kubectl` using command `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl` referring the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-via-curl).

I tried to install `Calico Kubernetes NetworkPolicy` using `kubectl` commands by refereeing [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.6/getting-started/kubernetes/tutorials/simple-policy) : `kubectl create ns policy-demo` creating namespace

This is then followed by creating nginx pod and services:

`kubectl run --namespace=policy-demo nginx --replicas=2 --image=nginx`

`kubectl expose --namespace=policy-demo deployment nginx --port=80`

Now, I want to uninstall and remove the policy-demo and namespace from the system.
Is there is ant way I can do it and remove this from my system using command?
How can I uninstall and remove the policy-demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing it.
You just need to use `kubectl delete ns policy-demo` to remove, clean and will delete the policy-demo namespace from the system using `kubectl` command.
It is already mentioned here in the end of the document: https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.6/getting-started/kubernetes/tutorials/simple-policy